# Arithmetic progressions of length N

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We say a set $A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length $N$ if it contains
a subset of the form $\{a, a + b, \ldots, a + (N − 1)b\}$ where $b \neq 0$. Show that if $A \subset [0, 1]$ with $\lambda(A) > 0$, then $A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length $N$ for every $N$. Here, $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I somehow would like to use density points, but I'm not really sure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know much about Lebesgue measure, so here are two suggestions based on vast ignorance: (1) Proof by contradiction; assume A doesn't contain an AP for some N and see what happens. (2) Do a binary search type proof, successively dividing the interval into two parts, choosing the part where $\lambda(p) > 0$ and, again see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K \subset A \subset V$ with $K$ compact, $V$ open, and $\lambda(K) > \frac{1}{1+\delta} \lambda(V)$ for some small $\delta$.  Let $U = (0,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ small enough that $K+U \subset V$.  This is possible because by compactness we can find a finite cover of $K$ contained in $V$ by open balls and take the minimum radius.

Let $u\in U$ and suppose that $\lambda( ( K+u ) \cap K ) < (1 - \delta)\lambda(K)$.  Then, since $K \cup (K+u) \subset V$, 
$$
\lambda(V) > \lambda( K ) + \lambda(K+u ) - \lambda( (K+u) \cap K ) > (1 + \delta )\cdot \lambda(K)
$$
 but we specifically chose $K$ and $V$ so that $(1 + \delta)\lambda(K) > \lambda(V)$, so this is a contradiction.  Therefore $\lambda( ( K+u ) \cap K ) \geq ( 1 - \delta ) \lambda(K)$.

Therefore, since $\delta$ did not depend on $u$, we get that $\lambda( K \cap ( K + \frac{m}{N}u ) ) \geq (1-\delta)\lambda(K) $.  From this, we get

$$
\lambda( K \cap ( K + \frac{1}{N}u )\cap \ldots \cap ( K + \frac{N-1}{N}u ) ) \geq ( 1 - N\delta ) \lambda( K ) > 0 
$$

In particular, since we could have chosen $\delta$ as small as we wanted, this intersection is non-empty, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: How do get the contradiction above from the preceding statement?

Comment: @copper.hat added some edits to expand on that part.

Comment: Thanks, @Callus. This looks very similar to the proof of the Steinhaus theorem...

Comment: @Hanna you're welcome. not surprising, as your question is very similar to the statement of the Steinhaus theorem. Perhaps there is a different proof of both statements that you could find along your original line of thought.

Comment: @Callus: Yeah, it's good to know about the theorem now (I didn't before today). After taking a closer look, I think the proof of Steinhaus uses density points in disguise, but the regularity of Lebesgue measure is more intuitive for me.